# If $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and $X \subset \mathbb{C}$ is closed and bounded then $f(X)$ is closed and bounded.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}$. I want to forget all others definitions or equivalent characterizations of compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ and only work with “A subset of the complex numbers is compact if is closed and bounded”.
With this definition I want prove the following:

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a compact subset and let $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function, then $f(X)$ is compact.

I have tried to take an accumulation point of $f(X)$ and prove that this point is in $f(X)$ but without success.

Could you give me some idea or help?

Thank you.

Comment: Definition of compact sets.

Comment: Yes. Continuous functions take compact sets to compact sets.

Comment: Yes i know that continuos function take compact to compact, the problem is the proof with this definition.

Comment: You may not be on the right track, since for closed $X$, $f(X)$ is not necessarily closed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be an accumulation point of $f(X)$.  Then there is a sequence $f(x_i)$ converging to $a$. The sequence $x_i$ in $X$ has a convergent subsequence because $X$ is compact. Let $x$ be the limit. What can you say about $f(x)$?

Comment: This uses another characterization of compactness (namely sequentially compactness), which is explicitely excluded in the question.

Comment: Well, it uses the fact that a bounded sequence has a limit point, which is characteristic of the reals, and cannot be avoided here. There are plenty of metric spaces where "closed and bounded" is not enough, so you have to use some structure of the reals here.